# What is more efficient? Table using NSMutableArray

Tags: nsmutablearray

`I have a table that is using`NSMutableArray`. When I refresh the table, I need to reload all the items in array.

I have 2 options

a) Recreate the new `NSMUtableArray` and throw away the old one

b) Remove all items from existing array and reload that again

From the performance/memory etc point of view what is the most efficient option in iOS world?

Comment: I would guess that doing removeAllObjects would be slightly more efficient, as it would not require allocating a new array, and the objects would have to be removed anyway if the array were  discarded.

Comment: Rather than asking us to guess you could try both methods and profile the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From performance perspective I think that the best bet would be instantiate a new NSMutableArray object, and just free the old one, or if you have ARC let the compiler to free the old object.

From the memory occupation perspective it would be better to clear the instance and reload it again, since you don't have two instances in any time in the application, however it could be useful only for large arrays.

*The best choice is relative to the context as in most case ...*

Answer (score 1):

Reusing the old `NSMutableArray` will be more efficient as that will reuse the same memory (memory is not released when you remove all elements from an array). It is unlikely this will affect performance in a notable way in your situation though, as you would need to do it thousands of times for it to have an impact on performance.